# How to change the name of an environment variable with a different variable?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a method to name an environment variable dynamically using another environment variable in a batch file?

Something like

```
numplayers=3
char%numplayer%atk=12 
echo char3atk
```

with output

```
12
```

Comment: Related: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward:

```
SET numplayers=3
SET char%numplayers%atk=12
ECHO %char3atk%
```

Comment: thank you I just realized i had a space in between the %% thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you are unlikely to know beforehand the number assigned to `%numplayers%`, here are a few ways you can see the value of the variable:

```bat
Set "numplayers=3"
Set "char%numplayers%atk=12"
Call Echo %%char%numplayers%atk%%
```

```bat
Set "numplayers=3"
Set "char%numplayers%atk=12"
Set char%numplayers%atk
```

```bat
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "numplayers=3"
Set "char%numplayers%atk=12"
Echo !char%numplayers%atk!
```