# echo variable value with another variables as part of name

Tags: windows, cmd

I have one variable is
MY_NODE_NAME
When I execute

```
echo %MY_NODE_NAME%,
```

I see its value, nodename1
but I have another variable, where value of MY_NODE_NAME is a part of and I need value of variable
my-supermode-%MY_NODE_NAME%
when I execute

```
echo my-supernode-%MY_NODE_NAME%,
```

I see answer my-supermode-nodename1, but I need a value. How can I receive value of this variable?

Comment: it is nearly but answer for me is 


    call echo %my-supernode-%MY_NODE_NAME%%

Comment: Right, that works at the interactive prompt. In a batch file you would need to double the outer `%`'s as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49985207/5538420) linked answer.